# Aluminum SER cable for 60 ft run

Tags: wiring

I plan to relocate a manual transfer switch (RONK 7103) to allow me to install in the future a solar system to power my essential loads
The switch is presently located between the main panel and an essential load panel (100A)
The new location is in the attached garage about 60 ft of wire away through an inside wall and the space above the garage to an external garage wall
I am considering a 2-2-2-4 SER aluminum cable for this

Comment: Some editing to actually ask whatever question you have to ask might help this. You do grasp that if you are relocating the switch, presently between your "Main" and "Essential loads" panels, you'll have to run a cable from **each** of those panels to the switch location...?

Comment: I understand that. I am asking whether the cable will be adequate for each leg of the run

Comment: Typically if your service is greater than 100A then No, because #2 Al is only good for 90A unless feeding the entire load associated with a residential service.

Comment: Thanks, I will have to rethink the plan to either shorten the distance by locating on a different wall, use copper or a 1-1-1-3 aluminum wire.  The price difference is significant

Comment: Well you can just put a 90A breaker in front of it instead of a 100A. There's no requirement for panel size to precisely match feed size.  Only needs to be >=.  (60A feed 100A panel is fine).  I would be surprised if aluminum 1-1-1-3 was all that much more.  Certainly #3 copper will be outrageous.

Comment: If you plan on using solar during power outages, you need batteries, if it's a net-metering setup, it won't work during a power outage. There are many sources on the internet showing wire capacities in various configurations (cable, individual wires in conduit, individual wires suspended outside, etc. etc.), sizes, temperatures and so on.   This site expects you to do at least a minimum amount of homework/research before asking for help here.   Not meaning to be rude, but do your homework.

Comment: My question is only about the wire options.

Comment: @George While getting grid-tie solar to work off-grid is complex, I think we'd be jumping the gun to assume OP hasn't done the research. As far as "many sources on the internet" for wire capacities, *that's exactly how OP got #2 for 100A*.  That particular case (#2, 100A) is the most misquoted thing in all of NEC, because people confuse feeders with services, or expect the answer to the be the same for a feeder vs a service. The phraseology of 310.15(B)(7) only muddies the water.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Thanks for the comment. I missed the spec in the OP.  And I certainly agree that getting solar to work with a grid tied system and batteries to work when the utility power is out is a complex situation with many compromises.   I have solar and it frustrates the heck out of me when I have to run a generator when the power is out, since I  have a large solar array.   I did lots of research and not very many good, cost effective solutions.   Thanks again for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

2-2-2-4 is a great choice as it is inexpensive aluminum wire, yet of a large enough size that no one disputes its safety. (aluminum has always been reliable in large feeder sizes).  Further it enjoys a cost and availability "sweet spot" due to its wide usage as 100A *service wire* to dwellings.

However, that 100A usage relies on a favorable derate granted to entire dwellings which receive 100A service: NEC 310.15(B)(7)   When the wire is used for feeder from a larger service than that, the normal rules apply - 310.15(B)(16) - giving it only 90A ampacity.

This is not a problem, however.

Your car tires probably have a mark like "112 MPH rating". That's only a redline limit; *you don't have to drive 112 mph!* The same applies to subpanels, transfer switches and the like which you might find rated at 100A. Anything will do <= 100A.

So a 90A feeder is perfectly fine. 90A is still an awful lot of power for an "emergency loads" panel.

Alternately you could make a wire size bump to 1-1-1-3 aluminum, which will be a bit more (you're not in that sweet spot anymore).  If cost is no object, 3-3-3-x copper wires are 100A, but most of the lugs you'd attach to will be made of aluminum.

Comment: Thanks for the response